# I installed nvm n and now I keep getting "dyld: bad external relocation length"

Tags: command-line, terminal, npm, iterm, nvm

I installed nvm, n, using sudo and decided to test it out by downloading several versions of node on my system. When I tried to switch between the node versions I kept getting "Permissions denied."  So I decided to sudo the command for switching between versions too. That's when all hell broke loose. I keep getting

```
dyld:bad external relocation length
```

I've tried to reboot my terminal with some hope that it would magically fix itself out. Alas, I was wrong.Thanks in Advance.

**Update 1**: I've tried to use npm to install yo and it gives me the same "dyld" prompt, along with the following:

```
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Essentially I can't use npm anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same thing happen.

I was using a mac, so I downloaded the `.pkg` for the version of node I was interested in and re-installed it (which reinstalls npm at the same time).

Everything was back up and running after that.

Comment: You are right. I basically broke my node installation. The error messages apparently don't come from npm but from os x. I uninstalled npm, node, and n, then reinstalled using nvm. All is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same this morning because of n package via npm,

Node was installed via brew (without npm), so i removed it this way;

```
brew uninstall node
```

then reinstalled the newer version via n package

```
n lts
```

if this is not enough because of policy rules of your mac, try

```
sudo npm lts
```

this solved my problem and saved a big time from reinstalling all global node modules.

Answer (score 0):

Just use n reinstall node that you break in.

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem wihout uninstalling the nodejs,just update the node version by n, and it works.

```
sudo n latest
```